# KonvaJS edit polygon vertex

Tags: polygon, edit, konvajs

I’m looking for a way to let user edit the vertex of polygon after drawn.
Here’s demo from fabricjs
http://fabricjs.com/custom-controls-polygon
Is there anything similar in Konva?

Comment: Take a look here: https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Modify_Curves_with_Anchor_Points.html

Comment: Thanks! I saw that before. So I need to implement all the controls as shapes and group them together I guess. FabricJS provides api for custom controls and events which is a bit easier.